# Getting "Stray end tag html" from W3C Validator

Tags: html

I'm checking my (HTML5) site using W3C's [validator](http://validator.w3.org/)  and getting the following error:

```
Stray end tag html. 
<html lang="en-US">
```

And the error sign is on the closing ">" there.
What is wrong with that line? It seems to be exactly right.

Comment: Read: http://nimbupani.com/declaring-languages-in-html-5.html

Comment: @ispiro, as you seem to have solved the problem on your own, please post the solution (exactly what did you have at the start and how you fixed it) and self-accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the minimum html that validates as html5 (except for the `lang="en-US"`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should have at least this structure

Comment: Thanks. It turns out the MasterPage had some stuff _before_ the html tag. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: No, the minimum is just `<!doctype html><title></title>`. I don’t see how this answer addresses the question asked and why it was approved.

Comment: From [w3c.org doc](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#a-quick-introduction-to-html) `The root element of this tree is the html element, which is the element always found at the root of HTML documents.` I read from there that the html tag is **always** at the root. IMHO that means it is mandatory. However the HTML5 validator is **experimenal**